# Mysql data extraction-Vba

Tags: mysql, vba, excel

I am vba code beginner. I am writing a vba code to extract data from mysql database. I have made successful connection with mysql server. Basically, database has 4 fields such as `id, id_id, descr` and `notation`.

I am trying to populate the combobox in userform by field list. Let say, I want to populate the `descr` list based on `id_id` field. I tried to create recordset as below

```
sqlQa = "select descr from matcat_select order by descr & id_id = int;"
```

FYI, `id_id` might be int or string.

See the code for data extraction from database and populate into Combobox

```
sqlQa = "select descr from matcat_select"
         Where id_id = 20
         Order by descr;"
'sqlQa = "select descr from matcat_select where id_id = 20;"

rs.Open sqlQa, oConn, adOpenStatic

With rs
  'Set .ActiveConnection = Nothing 'Disconnect the recordset
  .k = .Fields.Count

  'Populate the array with the whole recordset
  .vaData = .GetRows
End With

'Close the connection.
oConn.Close

'Manipulate the Combobox's properties and show the form.
With UserForm1
  With .ComboBox1
    .Clear
    .BoundColumn = k
    .List = Application.Transpose(vaData)
    .ListIndex = -1
    .ColumnCount = 2
  End With

  '.Show vbModal
End With
```

Please help me to solve this issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not sure if the `id_id` field is an `int` then input it as a string by surrounding it by single quotes.

Use where clause to fetch records for matching `id_id` value.

**Change**:

```
sqlQa = "select descr from matcat_select 
         order by descr & id_id = int;"
```

**To**:

```
sqlQa = "select descr from matcat_select 
         where id_id = 'value_of_id_id_here' 
         order by descr;"
```

Comment: Ravinder, thanks for ur help. I tried with your code nd got syntax error. I have pasted my code. Basically, i want to extract the descr list based on id_id value. Pls suggest me. tnks.

Comment: At which part of the code you got the syntax error? What was the error message?

Comment: While i paste below code in window, it shows compile error as Expected: end of statement. Sorry for confusion. sqlQa = "select descr from matcat_select"
         Where id_id = 20
         Order by descr;" Order by descr has been highlighted in red color

Comment: Remove the double quote before where clause after table name. That was unnecessary.

Comment: It should be `sqlQa = "select descr from matcat_select Where id_id = 20 Order by descr;"`

Comment: Works. but, got error 438. Object doesn't support this property or method. Error @ .k = fields.count. I have doubt in above code. sqlQa = "select descr from matcat_select Where id_id = 20 Order by descr;" Is there any AND command to evaluate both conditions ?

Comment: If `k` is your local field defined then try like `Me.k = .Fields.count`. And the sql query is correct unless it throws an error on column names or table name.

Comment: Doesn't work. Even i tried below code sqlQa = "select descr from matcat_select Where id_id = 20;". It shows error " ODBC properties doesn't support these properties.

Comment: I am beginner and it took while to understand how things work. Pls help me. tnks.

Comment: What is your table name? `matcat` or `matcat_select`. Correct query would be in the form of `"select descr from tableName where id_id=20;"`. Use correct table name.

Comment: Its matcat_select. Table name is correct. But, still get error.

Comment: On every line change of code and post your error in the comments, no one is going to understand what the error is. Try posting your attempted code and error message in your question. Not in the comments.

Comment: Ravinder, Tnks. I found solution.